# play-framework [2.0] - changing the models breaks my views

Tags: compiler-errors, playframework-2.0

I've been working with play for a week now and i found this weird problem:
each time i change anything in an entity all my views that use the entity start to give an error like this one:

```
value getId is not a member of models.UserData
```

it depends on the model i change. To fix this i have to remove all usages of that model in my views and refresh the browser, then it asks me to run a script to update my database, after that i have to reinsert all the usages of that model again and all the errors disappear, this is until i change any model again. By now you may see how annoying this gets if you have alot of views and you're team/supervisor decide to add or remove a field..

this is an example of my model:

```
@Entity
public class UserData extends Model {
    @Id
    @Constraints.Min(10)
public Long id;

@Constraints.Required
public String name;

@Constraints.Required
public String email;
....
}
```

and here is how i get a property inside a view:
    @user.getName()

I've also tried reloading and/or compiling the project at the console but doesn't make any difference. I've used both Eclipse and IntelliJ, as for the database i'm using MySQL.
My question is: is there a way to avoid this or am i doing something wrong? i've been looking over the internet and the play community but i cant find anyone having this problem it's so weird

ty for any assistance.

Comment: Do you use an IDE? I know IntelliJ has a "Refactor" function built-in to handle function changes, etc. I use Eclipse now but still learning the features ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that the get methods are generated after the views and the correct way was to use the property directly instead of the get methods